# Windows Subsystem for Linux - Passing arguments to commands on start

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am currently working on a setup to utilize wsl for my development needs. In order to do that I created wsl so that it works with systemd to enable the use of microk8s and other services that depend on systemd.

Now this brings me to a problem. I want to be able to start wsl and navigate to the directory I am currently in. Now

```sh
wsl /bin/bash
```

would just do that. Unfortunately bash will then bypass my /etc/profile.d scripts which will result in my init process being the one wsl set up instead of systemd.

Now I can easily pass an argument to any shell script inside of wsl as you would expect

**example.sh**

```sh
echo "Your argument is $1"
```

```sh
example.sh Hello World

# Output
# Your argument is Hello
```

But for some reason I was not able to do the same thing from outside

```sh
wsl /path/example.sh Hello
bash -c /paht/example.sh
```

all of those calls will not result in $1 containing anything. Any ideas how i could accomplish that?

Comment: I am confused. `wsl /bin/bash` will pass the argument `/bin/bash` which I suspect is passed as a kernel parameter invoking `/bin/bash` as the shell for wsl startup -- which would bypass the normal systemd targets. (more like a maintenance mode). I don't see how that is related to what you are trying to do from "outside" other than passing a script and parameter for that script. WSL has come a long way since I last looked at the options for its startup -- but do you have documentation telling you you can do what you are trying to do?

Comment: lets say for examle i use "wsl ls -la" then then -la will also be passed to ls. i want that same behaviour if i call "wsl my-script.sh some-val" but somehow $1 only gets filled inside the script if i run it from within wsl